# How to make my jQuery query selector perform AND and not OR

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got the Html below that includes a query selector as follows:

```
$("[make=gm],[model!=bolt]").show();
```

What appears to be happening is that it "or"s the values together because the result is everything shows.  How can I "and" the values so that I get just the "gm volt".  Also, any references to this would be helpful as I'm trying to understand it better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
            integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            $("[make=gm],[model!=bolt]").show();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div make="gm" model="volt">gm volt</div>
    <div make="gm" model="bolt">gm bolt</div>
    <div make="ford" model="mustang">ford mustang</div>
    <div make="ford">ford</div>
    <div test></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In jQuery use `.filter`

A prettier way of doing it in jQuery:

```
$("[make=gm]").filter("[model!=bolt]").show();
```

You can nest your if statements inside the `.filter()` selector modifier.

### Only CSS version.

For this, you can use the `:not` selector which will then make sure that all selected are **not** a certain type (for that matter you can also use jQuery's `.not()`:

```
$("[make=gm]:not([model=bolt])").show();
```

Refer to this jsfiddle for the full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfnneil/9bbqLfdw/

In **CSS** you can do an and by nesting `:not`.

```
$("[make=gm]:not(:not([model!=bolt]))").show();
```

Comment: Thanks @nfnneil.  If I want to do gm and ford and not bolt? how do I OR them? [make=ford][make=gm]:not(:not([model!=bolt]))?

Comment: Also, I need to stick to QuerySelector's.  I can't use jquery filter

Comment: I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: OK.  I"m marking your answer as correct since it 100% answers my question but still am wondering how to add an "or"

Comment: You'd have to do the selector twice: `$("[make=gm]:not(:not([model!=bolt])),[make=ford]:not(:not([model!=bolt]))")`

Comment: And thanks for marking solution, that's very nice of you.